# How to disable default checkbox event in JavaFX

Tags: checkbox, javafx

I want a `CheckBox` to be selected all the time but also disabled. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you share some code?

Answer (score 5):

From what I understood of your question, pls try:

```
checkBox.setSelected(true); 
checkBox.setDisable(true);
```